# Users not able to Download certain apps from Sharepoint store

Tags: sharepoint-store

Some of the apps are greyed out and users are complaining that they are not able to retrieve these apps from Sharepoint store.
The other apps from Sharepoint store are accessible. Can someone help me why and how can this be solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be resolved by configuring Internet facing endpoint feature. May be you have not configured your farm with this setting.

**Follow the steps :**

Central admin -> Application Management -> Manage Web application -> Choose your web application -> Manage features ->Apps that require accesible internet facing endpoints -> Activate.

This should solve your problem.